# accessing ms access table using a service in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

can we access the msacces table using a windows service which is created in vb.net. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can use an [`OleDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) with [this connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access) (or [this one](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007) for 2007 / 2010).
You can then execute arbitrary SQL statements on the connection.

Comment: Thanks! But i did it, to test my service i just build project and clicked the exe in project bin folder but nothing happend!, may be my code was wrong but when i looked into the task manager the service is running and when i clicked the end process, it didn't and still reopens. How should i solve this?